# Time complexity of Euler's totient function

Tags: complexity

I believe there are different time complexities for Euler's totient function depending on how you execute the algorithm. The two I know of are:

1. Iterate through 1 to k and calculate each $\gcd$: $O(n \log(n))$
2. Factor n first and then use Euler’s product formula: $O(n)$

Are there any other possibilities?

Comment: Both formulas are wrong. For the first, there seems to be a mix between $k$ and $n$, and calculating $\gcd(k,n)$ when $0<k<n$ has cost sizably larger than $O(\log n)$. For the second, factoring $n$ has cost much lower than $O(n)$.

Comment: [You may want to note that "computing the euler totient function of a number" is (roughly) as difficult as "factoring that number"](https://mathoverflow.net/a/3275), so don't expect anything better than "factor, then compute".

Comment: Euler's function is not itself an algorithm, and as such does not have a time complexity.  When you specify an algorithm, that algorithm will have a time complexity.  It depends, of course, on what units of ‘time’ you're counting ($\lg n$-bit multiplications? bit operations? communication costs?), including how much parallelism you can throw at it and what type of machine you have.